# Trying to get data to webserver

Tags: c#, xml, curl

This is the curl that works

curl -H "X-Auth-User: bryan" -H "X-Auth-Expires: 1406916006" -H "X-Auth-Key: 47ec7f890ef9fb2367c44b9dedcc2526" --ciphers "MD5" "-H" "Accept: application/xml" "-H" "Content-Type: application/xml" "-d" "@c:/projects/elemental/Job3.xml" "https://acb7b192c688.technologies.com/api/jobs"

This is the C# that doesn't it returns
A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "ElementalPostRequest": 
System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity.
System.Net.WebException: at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

Not sure what I have missed.

Bryan

```
public static void ElementalPostRequest(String url, String md5url, String elementalUser, String elementalApiKey, Xml XMLInput)
{

    TimeSpan t = (DateTime.UtcNow.AddSeconds(30) - new DateTime(1970, 1, 1));
    int timestamp = (int)t.TotalSeconds;

    string hash = CalculateMD5Hash(elementalApiKey + (CalculateMD5Hash(md5url + elementalUser + elementalApiKey + Convert.ToString(timestamp))));

    byte[] data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Convert.ToString(XMLInput));

    var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/xml";
    httpWebRequest.Accept = "application/xml";
    httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Auth-User: " + elementalUser);
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Expires: " +Convert.ToString(timestamp));
    httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Auth-Key: " + hash);
    httpWebRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;

    using (Stream stream = httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream())
    {
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    WebResponse response = httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string serverResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();

}
```

Comment: Just by the way, you can use `using` blocks to handle the closing your `reader`, `dataStream`, and `response`. That might be a bit clearer to read. It's the same functionality, but yeah. Just food for thought.

Comment: If you run your curl command with the -v option (verbose) you get the exact headers and content that is send and received. If you install [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) you can see the same for your c# program. Compare the two to see what you have missed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes this error message? The remote server returned an error: (422) Unprocessable Entity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/864661/what-causes-this-error-message-the-remote-server-returned-an-error-422-unpro)